# How do I order by lastname?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I order my list with people alphabetical? I have the people randomly in a list but I want it to be alpabetical ordered. How do I do that?

Here is my code:

```
@if (ViewBag.Roles.CanModify)
{
<div id="AlleLedenLijst" class="AlleLedenLijst" style="height: 20px;">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Zoek een lid" name="search" id="FilterLeden"><br />
    <p>Sleep naar een groep om deze toe te voegen</p>
    <ul id="catalog" style="height: 200px;">
        @foreach (var LedenA in Model.Groepen.AllMembers)
        {
            <li class="list-group-item" id="@LedenA.UserID"><a href="#" onclick="showPopup(@LedenA.UserID, @Model.Groepen.OrgID)">@LedenA.TVGS @LedenA.Anaam @LedenA.Vname</a></li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>
}
<div id="UserDetailsDiv" class="modal-dialog"></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`OrderBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for that:

```
@foreach (var LedenA in Model.Groepen.AllMembers.OrderBy(x => x.Anaam))
{ }
```

If you want to sort on the first name after that, use [`ThenBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534743(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
@foreach (var LedenA in Model.Groepen.AllMembers.OrderBy(x => x.Anaam).ThenBy(x => x.Vnaam))
{ }
```

Comment: Am I not already putting lastname in front of the firstname by saying, LedenA.TVGS, LedenA.Anaam, LedenA.Vname

Comment: You want to sort, right? If you have two members with the same last name, you then sort by the first name.

Comment: @Lucafraser the order in which you output the fields does not influence the order in which the `foreach` loops though the list. By adding a `OrderBy` inside that foreach, you *do* change the sort order.